# Using '' with open, reader '' functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I got a problem with this code:

```
import csv
with open('gios-pjp-data.csv', 'r') as data:
    l = []
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=';') 
    next(reader) 
    next(reader)  # I need to skip 2 lines here and dont know how to do it in other way
    l.append(# here is my problem that I will describe below)
```

So this file contains about 350 lines with 4 columns and
each one is built like this:

```
Date ; float number ; float number ; float number
```

Something like this:

```
2017-01-01;56.7;167.2;236.9
```

Now, I dont know how to build a function that would append first float number and third float number to the list on condition that its value is >200.
 Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: output : l= [236.9]

Answer (score 2):

List comprehentions if you don't have too many items in the file.

```
l = [x[1], x[3] for x in reader if x[1] > 200]
```

Or a similar function that would yield each line, if you have a huge number of entries.

```
def getitems():
    for x in reader:
        if x[1] > 200:
            yield x[1], x[3]

l = getitems()  # this is now an iterator, more memory efficient.
l = list(l)  # now its a list
```

Comment: you can do a gencomp as well no need for yield: `l = (x[1], x[3] for x in reader if x[1] > 200)`